# count records in a linked table as part of a mysql / rails query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a a view that necessarily displays about a thousand records. These are ideas from from clients (like a suggestion wall). I am doing the query in SQL as it's a lot faster. So in the `controller` I have two `actions`. These are

```
def index
  @ideas = ideas_index_data
end

def ideas_index_data
  ideas = Idea.publically_visible
    .select(
      "ideas.*, concat(users.first_name, ' ', users.last_name) as user_name ")
    .joins("inner join users on users.id = ideas.users_id")

  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query(ideas.to_sql)
end
```

In the `view` I can then do

```
@ideas.each do |idea|
  = i['description']
  %br
  = i['notes]
```

etc. This turns a 15 second query into a two second one. However, whilst I can easily get all the data from the `ideas` and `users` table, I need something a little more complex.

Each `idea` has a number of `likes` from the `idea_likes` table. I need to include in the `ideas_index_data` query the count of likes for each idea. So I need to extend the join and select sections of the query but so far no joy. Can anyone help. the `idea_likes` table references the `ideas` table with an `idea_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try something like this:

```
  ideas = Idea.publically_visible
    .select(
      "ideas.*, concat(users.first_name, ' ', users.last_name) as employee_name, COUNT(employee_likes.id) as number_likes ")
    .joins("inner join users on users.id = ideas.users_id left join employee_likes.idea_id = ideas.id")
    .group('ideas.id, users.id')
```